# How to see a plane with an image through a cube?

Tags: modeling

I have set up an image as a plane so that I can use it for a guide to make my model but I can't see through the main cube.

How can I set only the model cube to wireframe but NOT the plane so I can see it? Or what can I do to see the image plane through the cube?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object mode select the cube and turn on wire as per the image

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps! That helps a lot better now really appreciate your help! :)